# How to change %install section in spec file?

Tags: rpmbuild, rhel5, rhel6

I tried to build binaries in RHEL6 using rpmbuild command.It throws **file not found error** during rpmbuild command execution. But In RHEL5 the same rpmbuild command is working fine.

**RHEL5 execution result:**

*Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.77266

- umask 022
- cd /usr/src/redhat/BUILD
- LANG=C
- export LANG
- unset DISPLAY*

**RHEL6 execution result:**

*Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.BeMhyH

- umask 022
- cd //rpmbuild/BUILD
- '[' //rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/ '!=' / ']'
- rm -rf //rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/
  ++ dirname //rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/
- mkdir -p //rpmbuild/BUILDROOT
- mkdir //rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/
- LANG=C
- export LANG
- unset DISPLAY
- /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot*

I am not able to find any %install changes between the spec files. Any one please help me to understand what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance..!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that is clear from the snippets provided is that $HOME is not defined in your rpmbuild environment.  $HOME/rpmbuild is the default build root for 'rpmbuild' in RHEL6, instead of /usr/src/redhat as in RHEL5.

Things to consider:

- Is there an '~/.rpmmacros' file that is altering the rpmbuild
  directives.
- The temporary %install script will not be deleted on
  error-exit.  Inspecting it directly might tell you more about why it failed.

Ex:

```
[user@host rpmbuild]$ rpmbuild -bb nano
<snip>
+ exit 1
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.2uw1tZ (%install)

RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.2uw1tZ (%install)
[user@host rpmbuild]$ cat /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.2uw1tZ
#!/bin/sh

  RPM_SOURCE_DIR="/home/user/rpmbuild/SOURCES"
  RPM_BUILD_DIR="/home/user/rpmbuild/BUILD"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Older recommendations were to nuke the target buildroot as the first step of `%install`. To help force a separation between the `%build` and `%install` steps, newer versions of `rpmbuild` strictly enforce it by doing it for you for the first step, as shown in what you pasted in.

I am assuming that your `%build` stage is putting one or more files into the target buildroot area, which it shouldn't be doing. It should all be in the build area only.